# Equation of the Circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

How to find the **equation of a circle** if the givens are the:

Case 1:
Tangent to $2x + 3y + 13 = 0$ and $2x - 3y - 1 = 0$; contains $(0,4)$

Case 2:
Tangent to $x - 3y - 7 = 0$ and $3x + y - 21 = 0$; center on $x - 3y + 3 = 0$

Case 3:
Tangent to $x - y = 0$ at $(2,2)$; center on $2x + 3y - 7 = 0$

Case 4:
Tangent to $x^2 + y^2 - 22x + 20y + 77 = 0$ at $(91/17,10/17)$; containing $(0,1)$

**Please help**, I have no idea how to solve this problems. I've been stuck on these like forever.

Thank You

Comment: The basic idea is that the radius is perpendicular to the tangent.  Given a tangent line, the slope of the radius is the negative reciprocal.  In each problem, you are given enough information (in different forms) to find the center.  Make a sketch for each one, showing what you know.

Comment: I've sketch it but I have no idea how to answer it correctly, I always get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

**For case 1**. *Warning*: *this answer was given to the revision 1 of the question*. *In the present revision 2 the circle contains the point* $(0,4)$ *instead of the point* $(-2,-1)$.

I detail the computation as follows. Let the equation of the circle be
\begin{equation}
\left( x-h\right) ^{2}+\left( y-k\right) ^{2}=r^{2},  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $(h,k)$ is the center and $r$ the radius. The slopes of the tangent
lines

\begin{eqnarray}
2x+3y+13 &=&0  \tag{2} \\ 
&&   \\
2x-3y-1 &=&0  \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

are respectively $m_{1}=-2/3$ and $m_{2}=2/3$.  Solving this system of
equations $(2)$-$(3)$ we get $(x,y)=(-3,-7/3)$. Since the circle contains $P(-2,-1)$ its
center $C(h,k)$ should lie on the (symmetric) vertical line $x=-3$, which means that $h=-3$ and $r=\overline{CP}$:

\begin{equation}
r^{2}=(\overline{CP})^{2}=1+\left( -1-k\right) ^{2}=1+\left( 1+k\right) ^{2}.
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

[image: picture]

$$\text{Circle (red)} \left( x+3\right) ^{2}+( y-2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{39}) ^{2}=\frac{79}{4}+3\sqrt{39}$$

$$ \text{tangent to lines (2),(3) and containing point} (-2,-1)$$

Let $Q(s,t)$ be the point where the circle touches the line $(3)$. Then

\begin{equation*}
2s-3t-1=0\Leftrightarrow t=\frac{1}{3}\left( 2s-1\right) .
\end{equation*}

The slope $m$ of a line orthogonal to this tangent line is $m=-1/m_{2}=-3/2$; from this family of lines the equation of the one containing $Q$ is

\begin{equation*}
y-t=-\frac{3}{2}(x-s).
\end{equation*}

This line should intercept the vertical line $x=h=-3$ at $C$. Hence

\begin{equation*}
k=-\frac{3}{2}(-3-s)+t=\frac{3}{2}(3+s)+\frac{1}{3}\left( 2s-1\right) =\frac{1}{6}(25+13s).
\end{equation*}

To find $r$ we are going to equate $(\overline{CP})^{2}=(\overline{CQ})^{2}$. On the one hand, we have that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^{2} &=&(\overline{CQ})^{2}=\left( s-h\right) ^{2}+\left( t-k\right) ^{2} \\
&=&(s+3)^{2}+(\frac{1}{3}\left( 2s-1\right) -\frac{1}{6}(25+13s))^{2} \\
&=&\frac{1}{4}(13s^{2}+78s+117).\tag{5}
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^{2} &=&(\overline{CP})^{2}=1+(1+\frac{1}{6}(25+13s))^{2} \\
&=&\frac{1}{36}\left( 169s^{2}+806s+997\right)\tag{6} .
\end{eqnarray*}
So, equating $(5)$ and $(6)$ and simplifying yields 
\begin{equation*}
13s^{2}+26s-14=0\Leftrightarrow s_{1,2}=-1\pm \frac{3}{13}\sqrt{39}.
\end{equation*}

For the positive solution $s_{1}$, we find that
\begin{equation*}
s_{1}=-1+\frac{3}{13}\sqrt{39}.\tag{7}
\end{equation*}

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
k &=&\frac{1}{6}(25+13s)=2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{39}  \tag{8} \\
&&   \\
r^{2} &=&1+\left( 1+k\right) ^{2}=\frac{79}{4}+3\sqrt{39}.  \tag{9}
\end{eqnarray}

The equation of the circle is thus

\begin{equation}
\left( x+3\right) ^{2}+\left( y-2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{39}\right) ^{2}=\frac{79}{4}+3\sqrt{39}.  \tag{10}
\end{equation}

ADDED. For the negative solution $s_2$, we have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
s_{2} &=&-1-\frac{3}{13}\sqrt{39}\tag{11} \\
&& \\
k &=&\frac{1}{6}(25+13s)=2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{39}\tag{12} \\
&& \\
r^{2} &=&1+\left( 1+k\right) ^{2}=\frac{79}{4}-3\sqrt{39}.\tag{13}
\end{eqnarray*}

The equation of this second circle (the green one in the figure below) is thus

\begin{equation*}
\left( x+3\right) ^{2}+\left( y-2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{39}\right) ^{2}=\frac{79}{
4}-3\sqrt{39}.\tag{14}
\end{equation*}

[image]

$$ \text{The two circles: circle green } \left( x+3\right) ^{2}+\left( y-2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{39}\right) ^{2}=\frac{79}{
4}-3\sqrt{39}$$

$$ \text{tangent to lines (2),(3) and containing point} (-2,-1)$$

**For case 3**. Let the equation of the circle be as above

\begin{equation}
\left( x-h\right) ^{2}+\left( y-k\right) ^{2}=r^{2}.  \tag{15}
\end{equation}

The point $P(2,2)$ defines the condition

\begin{equation*}
\left( 2-h\right) ^{2}+\left( 2-k\right) ^{2}=r^{2},\tag{16}
\end{equation*}
Since the line orthogonal to the tangent line $x-y=0$ containing $P(2,2)$ is
given by the equation

\begin{equation*}
y-2=-(x-2),\tag{17}
\end{equation*}

the intersection of this line with the center line

\begin{equation*}
2x+3y-7=0\tag{18}
\end{equation*}

is the center $C(h,k)=C(5,-1)$. So

\begin{equation*}
r^{2}=\left( 2-h\right) ^{2}+\left( 2-k\right) ^{2}=\left( 2-5\right)
^{2}+\left( 2+1\right) ^{2}=18\tag{19}.
\end{equation*}

The  equation $(15)$ of the circle is thus

\begin{equation*}
\left( x-5\right) ^{2}+\left( y+1\right) ^{2}=18.\tag{20}
\end{equation*}

[image]

$$\text{Circle } \left( x-5\right) ^{2}+\left( y+1\right) ^{2}=18$$

Answer (score 0):

For case 1 and case 2, the center lies on the bisector of the angle of the given lines

For case 3, can you write the equation for the line perpendicular to $x-y=0$ and going through $(2,2)$?  Does that sound like the point-slope form?  Now you have two simultaneous equations with $2x+3y-7=0$

For case 4, you need to take the derivative to find the slope of the tangent.  Again you have a point-slope form.